# UIButton loses cornerRadius on scroll (when other properties are set)

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

I have a UIButton that needs to change background color and text when the user scrolls depending on where in the UIScrollView they are.

When they hit a threshold, I call the following function:

```
fileprivate func setFinalizeButton(format: FinalizeButtonFormat) {
    switch format {
    case ._continue:
        let grey = UIColor(red: 189, green: 189, blue: 189)
        finalizeButton?.setTitle("Continue", for: .normal)

        finalizeButton?.setBackgroundColor(color: grey, forState: .normal)
        finalizeButton?.setBackgroundColor(color: grey.darkerColor(percent: 0.2), forState: .highlighted)
    case .buyNow:
        finalizeButton?.setTitle("Buy Now", for: .normal)
        finalizeButton?.setBackgroundColor(color: .black, forState: .normal)
        finalizeButton?.setBackgroundColor(color: .black, forState: .highlighted)
    }
}
```

I've tried setting both `finalizeButton?.cornerRadius` and `finalizeButton?.layer.cornerRadius` and neither work. Both times the cornerRadius goes back to 0. (the button is initialized with a value of 5 for the cornerRadius)

Any idea why this is or how to fix it?

Thanks!

**Edit: Button setup**

```
let finalizeButton = UIButton()
    finalizeButton.cornerRadius = 5
    finalizeButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    finalizeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white.darkerColor(percent: 0.2), for: .highlighted)
    finalizeButton.backgroundColor = .black
    finalizeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(finalize(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    finalizeButton.setTitle("Buy Now", for: .normal) 
    finalizeButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
    bottomSection.addSubview(finalizeButton)

    constrain(finalizeButton) {
        $0.width == $0.superview!.width * CGFloat(0.8)
        $0.height == CGFloat(54)
        $0.bottom == $0.superview!.bottom - CGFloat(16)
        $0.centerX == $0.superview!.centerX
    }
    self.finalizeButton = finalizeButton
```

Comment: Possibly caused by code elsewhere? Please show _all_ of what you are doing to manipulate this button, not just what you _think_ is relevant.

Comment: That's it. I'll add the setup of the button too

Comment: @matt updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling this where you setup your button?:
finalizeButton.clipsToBounds = true
Let me know if this works.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!